# SwiftUI: How to only run code when the user stops typing in a TextField?

Tags: swift, swiftui, textfield, dispatch-queue

so I'm trying to make a search bar that doesn't run the code that displays the results until the user stops typing for 2 seconds (AKA it should reset a sort of timer when the user enters a new character). I tried using .onChange() and an AsyncAfter DispatchQueue and it's not working (I think I understand why the current implementation isn't working, but I'm not sure I'm even attack this problem the right way)...

```
struct SearchBarView: View {
    @State var text: String = ""
    @State var justUpdatedSuggestions: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            TextField("Search", text: self.$text).onChange(of: self.text, perform: { newText in
                appState.justUpdatedSuggestions = true
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3, execute: {
                    appState.justUpdatedSuggestions = false
                })
                if justUpdatedSuggestions == false {
                    //update suggestions
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The possible approach is to use `debounce` from Combine framework. To use that it is better to create separated view model with published property for search text.

Here is a demo. Prepared & tested with Xcode 12.4 / iOS 14.4.

```
import Combine

class SearchBarViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var text: String = ""
}

struct SearchBarView: View {
    @StateObject private var vm = SearchBarViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            TextField("Search", text: $vm.text)
                .onReceive(
                    vm.$text
                        .debounce(for: .seconds(2), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
                ) {
                    guard !$0.isEmpty else { return }
                    print(">> searching for: \($0)")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why we just don`t use a simple timer for this? It should solve the issue without using Combine.

Answer (score 15):

There are usually two most common techniques used when dealing with delaying search query calls: throttling or debouncing.

---

To implement these concepts in SwiftUI, you can use Combine frameworks throttle/debounce methods.

An example of that would look something like this:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private var disposeBag = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    @Published var text: String = ""

    init() {
        self.debounceTextChanges()
    }

    private func debounceTextChanges() {
        $text
            // 2 second debounce
            .debounce(for: 2, scheduler: RunLoop.main)

            // Called after 2 seconds when text stops updating (stoped typing)
            .sink {
                print("new text value: \($0)")
            }
            .store(in: &disposeBag)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        TextField("Search", text: $viewModel.text)
    }
}
```

---

You can read more about Combine and throttle/debounce in official documentation: [throttle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/fail/throttle(for:scheduler:latest:)), [debounce](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/fail/debounce(for:scheduler:options:))

Answer (score 3):

There's a fantastic **PropertyWrapper** solution to this by [CodeSlicing](https://www.youtube.com/@CodeSlicing) that lets you simply replace

`@State var text = ""`

with

`@DebouncedState var text = ""`

and you're done.

You can also set the amount of debouncing (which defaults to 0.3 seconds, or whatever you like). For a longer delay of 1.5 seconds: `@DebouncedState(delay: 1.5) var text = ""`

Here's his video: https://youtu.be/1uA0eKDT5-w

And his code: https://gist.github.com/CodeSlicing/026d8481dea0e4f5f5da85ea4dce6fc4