# SwiftUI: Filtering List with Custom Search bar

Tags: swift, swiftui, textfield, searchbar

I have created a custom search bar with `TextField` and trying to filter my List with it.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

My list consists of A to Z sections. Now I have a problem with filtering both section and list while searching which is returning nil. Here is my code:

```
@State private var searchText = ""
    let lists = loadGlossary().keys.sorted()
    let glossary = loadGlossary()

var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: -10) {
            
            //Navigation bar
            NavigationBarView(title: "Glossary", action: {}, titleColor: .primary, closeColor: .primary.opacity(0.5))
                .padding()
            
            //Search Bar
            TextField("Search", text: $searchText)
                .padding()
                .frame(height: 45)
                .background(.gray.opacity(0.1))
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
                .padding()
                .overlay {
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Button {
                            searchText = ""
                        } label: {
                            Label("clear", systemImage: "xmark.circle.fill")
                                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                .opacity(searchText.isEmpty ? 0 : 1)
                                .padding(30)
                        }
                        .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
                    }
                }
            
            //List
            List {
                ForEach(Array(wordDict.keys).sorted(by: <), id: \.self) { character in
                    ///Section
                    Section(header: Text("\(character)").font(Font.system(size:18, weight: .bold, design: .serif)).foregroundColor(.primary)) {
                        ///List
                        ForEach(wordDict[character] ?? [""], id: \.self) { word in
                            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
                                Text(word)
                                    .font(.system(size: 17, weight: .bold, design: .serif))
                                Divider()
                                Text(getDescription(word))
                                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                            }
                        }
                        .padding()
                    }
                }
                .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
            .padding(.top)
        }
    }
```

I would be grateful if you help to properly filter sections and items.

EDITED:
Changes:

```
@State private var wordDict: [String:[String]] = [:]

    func loadData() -> [String:[String]] {
        let letters = Set(lists.compactMap( { $0.first } ))
        var dict: [String:[String]] = [:]
        for letter in letters {
            dict[String(letter)] = lists.filter( { $0.first == letter } ).sorted()
        }
        return dict
    }
```

and load the first data here:

```
.onAppear {
        wordDict = loadData()
    }
```

and for `TextField` I have added:

```
TextField("Search", text: $searchText)
                    .onChange(of: searchText) {
                        wordDict = getFilteredWords(query: $0)
                    }
```

But when I clear the textfield of backspace the List won't update anymore

Comment: I’d definitely recommend looking into the searchable api that SwiftUI has available.

Comment: I know, but the searching only works with NavigationView ! I am using a custom navigation

Comment: you are not using the `searchText` anywhere, so where (which line) are you getting `...which is returning nil`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be that you could do the filtering like this:

1. Create a function which returns the filtered list
2. Render the results of the function to the screen.
3. Rerender the results on change.

Here is the function for your specific need under the following assumptions:

1. You didn't show us the structure of wordDict, so from your code snippet I assume that it is structured like this: `[String: [String]]`. (e.g. "A": ["apple", "Atari"])
2. You only want to show the sections where the entries contain part of the `searchText`. If you want to have more advanced querying capabilities the method would be the same, you just have to make minor adjustments to the function below.

```swift
func getFilteredWords(query: String) -> [String: [String]] {
    wordDict.mapValues({ entry in
        entry.filter({ word in word.lowercased().contains(query.lowercased()) })
    }).filter({ entry in !entry.value.isEmpty})
}
```

**What does the function do?**

The function takes the `searchText` and compares all of the entries of your `wordDict` with it. If the `wordDict` entry includes the part of `searchText` somewhere, it is kept. Otherwise it is discarded and therefore later not rendered. The comparison is case insensitive. After that, all of the categories without any entries are also discarded which prevents that your search still shows all categories even if they don't contain any entries.

**How to use it?**

1. Now you have do add the function above to your view struct.
2. Replace the `wordDict` instances in your `List`View with `getFilteredWords(query: searchText)`.

Comment: Just one question, the code is working fine, but what about when you clear x button on text field of when I try to delete the characters the worddict doesn't update. please check my edited Q

Comment: The problem is that `"".contains("") == false`, so inside of `getFilteredWords(...)` add (as first statement) `if query.isEmpty { return wordDict }` this checks if the searchbar is empty, and if so, it renders the entire `wordDict`. (You might also have to add another `return`  before `wordDict.mapValues...`)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible way

1. have a dynamic property of filtered items (it can be also in view model)

```
@State private var filteredWords: [String: String] = [:]
```

2. iterate UI over that filtered items instead of loaded words directly

```
ForEach(Array(filteredWords.keys).sorted(by: <), id: \.self) { character in
    ///Section
    Section(header: Text("\(character)").font(Font.system(size:18, weight: .bold, design: .serif)).foregroundColor(.primary)) {
        ///List
        ForEach(filteredWords[character] ?? [""], id: \.self) { word in
```

3. on initial load store loaded words and assign them to filtered

```
func load() {
   // ...
   self.wordDict = loadedData
   // assuming possible re-load apply existed filter
   self.filteredWords = applyFilter(data: loadedData, pattern: self.searchText)
}
```

4. apply filter to originally loaded words on search field changes

```
TextField("Search", text: $searchText)
  .onChange(of: searchText) {
     self.filteredWords = applyFilter(data: self.wordDict, pattern: $0)
  }
```

or with view model and publishers to debounce ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66186675/12299030))