# Call function and pass parameter when Timer is done in Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui, timer

I'm trying to save the value entered in a `textField` 2 seconds after the user stops typing. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66186451/swiftui-how-to-only-run-code-when-the-user-stops-typing-in-a-textfield) example that uses `.debounce` from the `Combine` framework which works fine but for some reason, it feels like I overcomplicated things and I would rather use a simple timer.

The issue with the following code is that I cannot pass the value from the `logInputValue(inputValue:)` method to the `doSomething()` method when the timer is done. Right now it calls the `doSomething()` method but it doesn't pass any parameter.

**How can I pass a string parameter from the `logInputValue(inputValue:)` method to the `doSomething()` method when the timer is done?**

#### Service Model

```
class ServiceModel{
    var myTimer = Timer()
    
    func logInputValue(inputValue:String){
        if myTimer.isValid{
            myTimer.invalidate()
        }
        myTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: #selector(doSomething), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }
    @objc func doSomething(){
        print("Timer is done")
        // save the value currenlty in the textField
    }
}
```

#### SwiftUI

```
TextField('enter number', text: $myTextField)
    .onChange(of: myTextField) { value in
        serivceModel.logInputValue(inputValue: value)
    }
```

I also tried using the timer as follows but couldn't make it work. It saves each character typed in the field not just what's in the field after the 2 seconds after the user stops typing.

```
func logInputValue(inputValue:String){
    self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: false, block: { _ in
        if timer.isValid{
            timer.invalidate()
        }
        // save the value currenlty in the myTextField
    })
}
```

Comment: Actually your attempt is much more complicated than a `Combine` publisher with the `debounce` operator.

Comment: I feel that with my current code structure, it makes more sense to use the timer since I'm not using `ViewModels` to hold my TextFields and I have a few more fields, and having just one in a ViewModel feels wrong.  FYI - I'm using more of a `ServiceModel` approach in this project. Thanks.

Comment: IMHO, using Combine in the ServiceModel would in fact yield the most comprehensible code. Especially, since you already have  a function that feeds the input PassthroughSubject, i.e. `input.send(inputValue)`. You may give Combine a try ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a version of `Timer` that runs with a closure instead of a `selector`:

```
myTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2.0, repeats: false) { [weak self] _ in
    self?.doSomething(inputValue)
}

// ...

func doSomething(_ value: String) {
  // ...
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/2091889-scheduledtimer

Comment: Shoot, it works, as I stated in my original comment, it didn't work when I tried the closure.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I want to provide a solution using Combine to let you see the difference to the other suggested solutions. You can judge for yourself whether this is "overcomplicated things" ;)

```
import Combine

class ServiceModel {
    private let input = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()
    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable!

    init() {
        self.cancellable = input
        .debounce(for: .seconds(2), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
        .sink { [weak self] value in 
            // ...
        }
    }
    
    func logInputValue(inputValue:String) {
        input.send(inputValue)
    }
}
```