Keyboard (TextField) in SwiftUI iOS app hangs/lags, why?
I'm creating a dictionary application as a personal project. I'm loading in a text file with 70,000 lines of strings (about 2MB). When typing in the keyboard, the key strokes hang, creating a frustrating lag for UX (can type like one character per second max). I'd like to know why. I've been debugging this application for the last week. At first, I thought it was the filtering operations when the user searches for text that was slowing everything down. So I created the TextField with debounce logic, to limit the number of times the filtering would happen (e.g. if I user typed keys with less than 800 miliseconds it wouldn't filter on each individual keystroke, saving time of looping over the entire dictionary unnecessarily until the user paused for 800ms). Shockingly to me, this did not help. I could see that the filtering would execute only after 800 seconds, but the text field was still lagging when typing. I then put all that filtering logic into a Dispatch Queue to run on a secondary thread. That didn't help. I then removed the filtering operations entirely, and the keyboard lag still persists!
I've since stripped my code piece by piece, and got it down to this bare-bones project you see below. I thought that logically it will take a few seconds on first launch to load the file into dictionaryStrings. Fair enough. But even if I launch the app, wait 20 seconds (to ensure file is completely done loading into memory), and then start typing, the keyboard sill lags. However, I can scroll through the 70,000 wordlist just fine. There is no hang there. The hang is only on the TextField, which is not even interacting with or searching through the dictionaryStrings array.
Could somebody explain to me why the keyboard is lagging, and what I can do to resolve it? Many thanks in advance.
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class SearchViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var text: String = ""
}

struct SearchView: View {

@Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
@StateObject private var searchViewModel = SearchViewModel()

// Reading in a txt file of 70,000 lines of strings, each with a Spanish word and its English equivalent
@State var dictionaryStrings = (readFileIntoStringArray(fileName: "dictionaryFile")).sorted{$0 < $1}

var body: some View {
    VStack() {
        Spacer()
        List(dictionaryStrings, id: \.self) { dictionaryLine in
            Text(dictionaryLine)
            .listStyle(.plain)
            .scrollDismissesKeyboard(.interactively)
        }
        
        let borderColor = colorScheme == .dark ? Color.white : Color.black
        TextField("Search Spanish or English", text: $searchViewModel.text)
            .padding()
            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0).strokeBorder(borderColor, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 1.5)))
            .padding()
            .onReceive(searchViewModel.$text.debounce(for: .milliseconds(800), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)) {_ in
                // Removed all work
            }
            .modifier(TextFieldClearButton(text: $searchViewModel.text))
    } 
} 


You've got things the wrong way around, ObservableObject should be for the model data, i.e. the data read in from file. @State is for the view model data, i.e. the search text.

70,000 lines all sitting in memory, all reloading into the body. Look for a different approach with a proper query mechanism.

@malhal do I have things wrong? ObservableObject is for debounce in order to execute work functions only when user stops typing
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66186675/7794924

@loremipsum But I can scroll through the 70,000 word list just fine. There is no hang there. The hang is only on the TextField, which is not even interacting or searching through the dictionaryStrings array above. And the 70,000 lines is less than 2MB. My phone loads websites with image files that are bigger than that, but there is no impact on TextField lag when typing on those sites. Maybe later I can go with a different approach, but the purpose of this post was to learn and understand exactly why the TextField lags while the user is typing

The solution is to add .id(UUID()) to the List
This tutorial explains in more detail
List(dictionaryStrings, id: \.self) { dictionaryLine in
        Text(dictionaryLine)
        .listStyle(.plain)
        .scrollDismissesKeyboard(.interactively)
    }
    .id(UUID())

